# What are the sha256 repositories when deleting a Docker image?

Tags: docker

This is after already doing a `docker system prune`.
When I tried `docker image rm 21cfe64741c1`, I got an error `Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 21cfe64741c1 (must be forced) - image is referenced in multiple repositories`. When I do a force deletion, three other repositories with some sha256 hash id, got deleted. The ones indicated with the red arrow in the image below.

[image]

However, when I had tried `docker container ls` or `docker images`, I didn't see any of those repositories.

What are those "secret" repositories? Didn't find any info about it [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/).

Comment: The lines beginning with `Deleted` are layers getting deleted.

Comment: @tkausl: That's obvious. I'm asking what those repositories are. From my understanding, a Docker image is like a Virtual Box image. So I don't see what "layers" or extra "repositories" would be present in an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker image comprises layers and whenever you remove an image it'll delete the associated layers tagged to that image.

You can find the layers of the image in the folder `/var/lib/docker/aufs/layers`; provide if you have configured for storage-driver as `aufs`.

For example, you want to view the layers of the image follow the below steps:

Find the image ID using:

`$ docker images -a`

Find the layers of the image using:

`$ docker history --no-trunc <Image ID>`

The layers are nodes of a Merkle filesystem. More info here:[What exactly is the information passing and Docker intermediate container creation during builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68622702/what-exactly-is-the-information-passing-and-docker-intermediate-container-creati)

Answer (score 0):

use $ docker rmi [imageID]

Docker image List
$ docker images

Docker image delete
$ docker rmi [imageID]

Docker image delete with container
$ docker rmi -f [imageID]